# ClassDoc - help to find example

Tags: java, javadoc

I am reading the [ClassDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/ClassDoc.html) documentation. But for some reason I cannot find any code snippet or a tutorial to see how it works with a class or how to wrap a class for the ClassDoc... :S

Please share some code snippets or tutorial links. I am dearly hope for your help.

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple use of ClassDoc can be something like this:

```
public static void start(RootDoc root) {
       ClassDoc[] classes = root.classes();
        for (ClassDoc cd : classes) {
            System.out.println("Class [" + cd + "] has the following methods");
            for(MemberDoc md : cd.methods()) {
               System.out.println("  " + md);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but I am looking for some kind of snippet which is showing a jar class wrapping... for example how to get ClassDoc of JButton for example? I am not pretty sure how to use it in that case :S

Comment: Is there a way to use Doclet for Swing objects for example?

Comment: Check http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2001/jw-0302-doclets.html?page=2 , a useful article from javaworld. It is straightforward and I think that will help you understand the whole concept beyond doclets.